# async/await not waiting for returning value

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, async-await

I have a async function in controller which should await on another service function returning value, but it's not waiting on it. If only one (or the best) way to resolve this problem is to return new Promise despite just value?
Controller code

```
exports.trip = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    let result = await osrmService.trip(req.body.options);
    console.log(result) //result is undefined
    res.status(200).json({
        route: result
    });
} catch (error) {
    next(error)
}
```

osrmService code: (not waiting for value)

```
exports.trip = async (options) => {
osrm.trip(options, await function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //console.log(result)
    return result;
});
```

I did it in this way and its working correctly:

```
exports.trip = (options) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    osrm.trip(options, function (err, result) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(result)
    });
});
```

Is it the optimal way?

Answer (score 0):

use promise to return the value and resolve that before returning it to main function

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I think you'r wrong with your osrmService. You should make it return the value of the `osrm.trip` either by adding a `return` behind `osrm.trip` or by removing the curly braces. Here's an example :

```
exports.trip = async (options) => {
  return osrm.trip(options, await function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      //console.log(result)
      return result;
  });
}
```

Or

```
exports.trip = async (options) => osrm.trip(options, await function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      //console.log(result)
      return result;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you did by returning the Promise is optimal way. Whenever you need to use async/await the function to which you add await should be a promise returning function to make it wait until it get's resolved

Answer (score 0):

check this one as well

```
exports.trip = async (options) => {
    try{

      const result = await osrm.trip(options)
      return result;
    }catch(err){
        throw err;
     }
});
```

BTW your method for returning promise is fine as well, both of these implementations return a promise object

Answer (score 0):

Issue is osrm.trip function is asynchronous and by the time callback is invoked, the execution flow has already been returned from the function. Basically it returns undefined in your case. Solution would be to wrap that function inside promise.